# How to say "we put something under a square root"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, mathematics

I would like to say that "we put something under a square root" in a math formula. For example my sentence is

> The reason for putting the original distances under square root is discussed later.

Here, the original distance was

d_o(x,y) = ...

and my distance is

d_my(x,y) = sqrt( d_o(x,y) )

Maybe the sentence

> The reason for square rooting the original distance is discussed later.

would be the right phrasing?

Comment: Is the reason for taking the square root of the original distance going to be discussed?

Comment: https://boards.straightdope.com/t/is-there-a-verb-form-for-square-root/426733/8 suggests that there might not be a valid answer to my question...!?

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, in the publication I am writing. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, look at the structure of my sentence above and compare it to your original sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The reason for putting the original distances under square root is discussed later.

The reason for taking/using the square root of the original distances is discussed later.